# Magento 2 How to get reward point data in Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2, php, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm trying to get Cart price rule data. However, I cannot get the `reward point` which I created in `Add reward point` input field in Cart price rule form from the database, I have found it in `salesrule` and its related table, but I cannot find where the `reward point` was saved. How the mechanism of saving reward point action?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The current customers' reward points can be checked in the `magento_reward` table
2. Reward points history (when they were added/ subtracted) in the `magento_reward_history` table
3. Rule-2-points relation is found in `magento_reward_salesrule`

Good luck!

Comment: thank you, I found it in `magento_reward_salesrule` table, then I wonder how I can retrieve it to get its data?